# Best way to manage customizable texts in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, text, symfony-2.8, xliff

Anybody knows what's the best way to manage customizable texts in Symfony 2 like Wordpress?

I.E: slider titles, button texts, etc....

I'm implementing a simple BD table with customizable texts and then call it (array) before render the twig, but I think that exists a better way to do this. By XLIFF files for example?

Thanks a lot! :)

PD: Symfony 2.8 version

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, take a look at the [Translation Component in Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html). You can store your button texts in a YAML file or something similar (seems like XLIFF) is supported and use those in your Twig templates.

Comment: I'm trying that :). It's possible to exclude the cache/translations folder?